# BATCH: Search CSV based on identifier then store row into variables

Tags: loops, csv, parsing, batch-file

I want search a CSV document using Batch based on a given input (e.g. 33355 = ID) if this condition is true, then store the rows data into variables e.g. (Mike = Name) and (C:\Name\222 = path).

So far I have managed to store every line of the CSV into a variable (var0-var999). The For loop iterates across every row in the spreadsheet and assigns a variable to each row e.g. %VAR1%...%VARN%. Given the line number e.g. VAR2, seperate the into variables (A, B, C) however I am stuck on how to achieve the CSV search functionality based on the identifier.

The screenshot below is a small example of the content that is contained in my spreadsheet. There is a maximum of three columns and approximatly 1500 rows. First column will contains the ID of the person, second column will be the name and third will be a path to a local folder.

[image: Excel]

CSV CONTENTS

```
ID,Name,Path
9353,Lol,C:\Name\lol
33355,222,C:\Name\222
5533,ABC,C:\Name\ABC
```

BATCH SCRIPT

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set test=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\COMMON\Desktop\test\test.csv) do (
    SET /A test=!test! + 1
    set var!test!=%%A
)
set var
REM set list=%VAR2%

FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a IN ("%VAR2%") DO (
   set a=%%a
   set b=%%b
   set c=%%c
)

ECHO %c%

PAUSE
```

[image: Command]

The second challange I am facing is my main Excel spreadsheet contains over 1000 records. Using the Batch script I can see that execution halts after storing 999 variables. Based on the output I dont believe that parsing and storing each line into variables is the most efficient way to perform my requirement.

I appreciate your input and feedback and await your response.

Many Thanks!

Manifesto

Comment: We need to see the CSV content not what the file looks like inside a running spreadsheet. We need to know exactly what you're wanting to have as output and in what form. I would also appreciate an explanation of the variable `%VAR2%` in the script you've posted. Do not add that information to a comment or answer, update your initial question by using the edit facility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do it.  Note I have set the target id as a fixed value for this example; I am also assuming the CSV file in your question.  In practice you'd probably supply the id as a .bat file argument.

```
@echo off& setlocal

set id=33355

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.csv) do (
  for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%b in ("%%a") do (
      if %%b==%id% set name=%%c & set pth=%%d
  )
)

echo id=%id%, name=%name%, pth=%pth%
pause
```

Comment: Absolute legend! thank you, everyone, for your help and support!